# Select ith row in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select the ith row in an excel spreadsheet through a for loop in vba and it keeps giving me an object defined error. I am new to vba and it is really confusing me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("i").Select
```

Comment: If you have i defined as a variable within your for loop you reference it as just i not "i" so it would be wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Select.

Comment: @BradyK: Please post it as an answer as comments are temporary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment:

If you have `i` defined as a variable within your for loop you reference it as just `i` not "i" so it would be `wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Select`